# Ruby on rails cross-platform win/linux script

Tags: ruby, linux, windows

I want to list the files/directories in a subdirectory using a Ruby on Rails application, but I don't know if the script will run under Linux or Windows.

On linux this is easy, I can just do a

```
`find my_path`.split("\n").each{|line| do_sthing_with_line}
```

On windows, the equivalent would be to use the `dir` command. But even after reading many posts on this, I can't figure out a way to make it work correctly

```
`dir my_path` will output a string that is recognized as ruby as utf-8, but which in reality isn't.
```

What's the correct way to make it work on windows ?
Is there a quick way to check if I'm on windows or not ? `on_windows? dir_command : find_command`

EDIT : and is there a fast way to generate a tree view of the content of a directory like this ?

```
-- rails_app
-- -- app/
-- -- -- models/
-- -- -- controllers/
-- -- -- views/
-- -- bin/
-- -- config/
etc.
```

Comment: This is one of those situations where traditional Ruby thinking, using system tools and capabilities instead of language features, kind of falls flat when you try to be platform inclusive. It's just a trade off of being pragmatic or thorough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a subcommand at all. The builtin `Dir.glob` should work in this case.

Something like:

```
Dir.glob("#{path}/**/**").each { |fileOrDir| do_something }
```

In any case, your `find` is recursive, but your `dir` wouldn't be.

If you *really* want to know if running on Windows, there are some Ruby-centric ways, but for years I have been checking for the `WINDIR` variable in the environment, e.g.

```
if ENV["WINDIR"]
    puts "On Windows"
else
    puts "Not Windows *probably*"
end
```

EDIT:  Here is a tool I wrote years ago that generates a tree of Nodes and then displays them sorted in various ways.

```
def usage
    puts <<END
Recursive listing of files or dirs, sortable by date or size or count.
    rl [-cdfnrsuv] [-p pathname] [pathname ...]
Where:
    pathname = Dir or file to process; default is ".".
    -c = Sort by file count; default is sort by date.
    -d = List dirs only, with their contents sizes and counts.
    -f = List files only, no dirs or links.
    -n = Sort by name; default is sort by date.
    -p = Add pathname even if it starts with "-".
    -r = Reverse sort order; default order is desc, except by name is asc.
    -s = Sort by size; default is sort by date.
    -u = Unsorted; default is sort by date.
    -v = Verbose, including type, perms, and owner.
END
    exit(1)
end # usage

class Node
    attr_reader :path, :stat
    def load(path)
        @path, @stat, @children = path, File.lstat(path), []
        @stat.directory? and Dir.glob("#{path}/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).each { |sub_path|
            sub_path[-2,2] != "/." && sub_path[-3,3] != "/.." and @children << Node.new.load(sub_path)
        }
        self
    end
    def size
        @size or @size = self.stat.directory? ? (@children.inject(0) { |acc, child| acc + child.size }) : @stat.size
    end
    def count
        @count or @count = self.stat.directory? ? (@children.inject(0) { |acc, child| acc + child.count }) : 1
    end
    def to_a
        @children.map { |child| child.to_a }.flatten + [self]
    end
end # Node

only_dirs = only_files = by_count = by_name = by_sz = verbose = false; sort = 1; paths = []
while (arg = ARGV.shift)
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*[h?]/ and usage
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*c/ and by_count = true
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*d/ and only_dirs = true
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*f/ and only_files = true
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*n/ and by_name = true
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*r/ and sort *= -1
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*s/ and by_sz = true
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*u/ and sort = 0
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*v/ and verbose = true
    arg =~ /^-[^-]*p/ and paths << ARGV.shift
    arg !~ /^-/       and paths << arg
end
nodes = (paths.empty? ? ["."] : paths).map { |path| Node.new.load(path).to_a }.flatten
if sort != 0
    if    by_sz    then nodes.sort! { |a, b| sort * (2 * (b.size <=> a.size) + (a.path <=> b.path)) }
    elsif by_count then nodes.sort! { |a, b| sort * (2 * (b.count <=> a.count) + (a.path <=> b.path)) }
    elsif by_name  then nodes.sort! { |a, b| sort * (a.path <=> b.path) }
    else  nodes.sort! { |a, b| sort * (2 * (b.stat.mtime <=> a.stat.mtime) + (a.path <=> b.path)) }
    end
end
for node in nodes
    next if only_dirs && ! node.stat.directory?
    next if only_files && ! node.stat.file?
    puts "%s %11s %6s %s%s" % [
        node.stat.mtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        node.size.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)(?!\d*\.)/, "\\1,").reverse,
        node.count.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)(?!\d*\.)/, "\\1,").reverse,
        verbose ? "%-9s %6o %4d %4d " % [:ftype, :mode, :uid, :gid].map { |v| node.stat.send(v) } : "",
        node.path]
end
```

Comment: Just another little tidbit, your `find` would also give names starting with `.`, but the `Dir.glob` wouldn't unless rewritten as: `Dir.glob("#{path}/**/**", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)`, AND you would need to ignore paths ending in `"/."` or `"/.."`.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Is there a fast way to generate a tree-like view with this ? (see my edit)

Comment: I added a bit of code, it should have parts that you can use for a tree of dir or file nodes in your own code.